# Getting log file as it is using Elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

**Info:**

Filebeat is installed on machine from where logs will be read and sent to elastic search server. From test machine, using `elasticsearch-dsl`, I am reading logs and writing it to file.

**Problem:**

Orig Log from machine :

```
[Timestamp][INFO] AAAAAA
[Timestamp][INFO] BBBBBB
[Timestamp][INFO] CCCCCC
```

After searching and writing logs to output file :

```
[Timestamp][INFO] CCCCCC
[Timestamp][INFO] AAAAAA
[Timestamp][INFO] BBBBBB
```

How to keep the sequence of log intact or as it is?

**Code :**

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, Index
import time
#Make Connection
es =  Elasticsearch(["100.16.13.222:9200"])

#Create Index Object
ind = Index("filebeat-*",using=es)
#Clear Cache
ind.clear_cache()
#Create Search object for this index
sear = ind.search()

#Create query
sear =  sear.query("match",host="WIN-LK9FS7568K4").query("match",tags="old_log")
res = sear.execute(ignore_cache=True)
print int(res.hits.total)

with open("a.txt","w") as fh:
    for i in sear.scan():
        fh.write(i.message+"\n")
```

Comment: In your search, you need to sort your logs by timestamp

Comment: Val -  There will be two time stamp. Time stamp due to elastic search and time stamp of logs. How to sort using time stamp of logs?

Comment: @Val - Can you please help me. How to use regexp in query using python elasticsearch-dsl?

Comment: Please provide the code you're using now. it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: @Val - Code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort your logs by timestamp. Change your search code to this:

```
sear =  sear.sort('timestamp')
            .query("match",host="WIN-LK9FS7568K4")
            .query("match",tags="old_log")
```

Of course you need to change `timestamp` to match your timestamp field.

Comment: Thanks for help !!! One more question. How to search using "offset"? I have tried sear.sort("offset") but it is not sorting

Comment: This is described [here](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#pagination), simply using the Python slicing API.